# How do I await on a collection of Tasks?

Tags: c#, async-await

This gives me a `List<T>` result which is performed asynchronously:

```
var result1 = await foo.doSomething().ToList();
```

This gives me a `List<Task<T>>` result:

```
var result2 = bar.Select(async b => await b.doSomething()).ToList();
```

But I want a `List<T>`, and I want it performed asynchronously. How do I unwrap that collection of tasks asynchronously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `await Task.WhenAll(foo.doSomething())`.